# Chromium Embedded Framework - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves'

Tags: python, java, cmake, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to run CMAKE -G "Visual Studio 17" -A x64 .. as indicated in https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef.git.

But this results in the error:

```
 -- Downloading clang-format from Google Storage...
 Failed to fetch file gs://chromium-clang-format/66882fadbf9e99cc00b8677d8c1e7e8b3cfdf4fe 
 ...
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves'
```

Obs. I already tried without success:

```
 python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
 pip install --ignore-installed six
```

And also add into download_from_google_storage.py

```
import six
```

Comment: Additional: CMAKE 3.28.0,

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.7.6 - Visual C++ 2022   00482-90000-00000-AA353

Comment: Python 3.12 and Java 11.0.10

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your version of python.

In the documentation, it is written that supported versions of python includes 2.7.x and 3.9.x, while you said you used python 3.12.

> 2. Install Python. Version 2.7.x or 3.9.x is required. If Python is not installed to the default location you can set the `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE` environment variable before running CMake (watch for errors during the CMake generation step below).

If you are using this version for other projects and don't want to change, you can install another version elsewhere and set the environment variable `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE` to the python executable of the version you just installed.